# Logstash use file plugin as input for a query using jdbc

Tags: elasticsearch, jdbc, logstash

I would like to use 1 logstash pipeline(on windows server) for multiple sites.
This pipeline reads some records out of a database.
But the connection string should be dynamic and depending on which site the current logstash is running.

I am trying to read the context of a file and then use that result for my connectionstring and then get the data out of the db.
I was able to just execute the query on 1 site using a hardcoded value so that is not the problem.

This is my logstash conf:

```
input {
 beats {
    host => "0.0.0.0"
    port => "9338"
    ssl => false
  }

  file {
    path => "C:/logstash/connection/connection-string.conf"
    mode => "read"
    start_position => "beginning"
  }


    jdbc {
        jdbc_driver_library => "C:\logstash\logstash-core\lib\jars\mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
        jdbc_connection_string => "%{message}"
        jdbc_user => "my cool user"
        jdbc_password => "Some password"
        schedule => "* * * * *"
        statement => "SELECT TOP 2000 * FROM ACTMesDb..LTA_Logging WHERE TimestampUTC >= DATEADD(MINUTE, -61, GETUTCDATE()) ORDER BY TimestampUTC DESC"
    }
}
filter {

  mutate {
    add_field => {
      "message" => "Status: '%{[status]}' for action: '%{[action]}' with type: '%{[type]}' with comment: '%{[comment]}'"
    }
  }

#Some other stuff happens here

}

output
{
 elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://myIP"]
    ilm_rollover_alias => "pur-mes-schedtask"
    ilm_pattern => "000001"
    ilm_policy => "some-policy"
    ilm_enabled => true
 }
}
```

The query never gets executed if I search for it with the SQLprofiler.
According to the logging I can see some jdbc logging:

```
[2023-07-07T11:31:42,915][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] config LogStash::Inputs::Jdbc/@schedule = "* * * * *"
[2023-07-07T11:31:42,916][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] config LogStash::Inputs::Jdbc/@jdbc_password = <password>
[2023-07-07T11:31:42,916][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] config LogStash::Inputs::Jdbc/@statement = "SELECT TOP 2000 * FROM ACTMesDb..LTA_Logging WHERE TimestampUTC >= DATEADD(MINUTE, -61, GETUTCDATE()) ORDER BY TimestampUTC DESC"
[2023-07-07T11:31:42,916][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] config LogStash::Inputs::Jdbc/@jdbc_driver_library = "C:\\logstash\\logstash-core\\lib\\jars\\mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar"
[2023-07-07T11:31:42,917][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] config LogStash::Inputs::Jdbc/@jdbc_connection_string = "%{message}"
[2023-07-07T11:31:42,917][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] config LogStash::Inputs::Jdbc/@id = "de1f3b31bc779b39629b00a963243f66032a72002b13971cdc982887f938d57b"
[2023-07-07T11:31:42,917][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] config LogStash::Inputs::Jdbc/@jdbc_driver_class = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
[2023-07-07T11:31:42,917][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] config LogStash::Inputs::Jdbc/@enable_metric = true
```

How can I make this work
Or is this not the correct way to implement this?

Thanks in advance!